# How can I use the value of an Excel cell in an Office Data Connection SQL query with an IN operator?

Tags: microsoft-excel, parameters, external-data

I've got an Office Data Connection running a SQL query against an external data source and using some dynamic parameters provided in cell in a worksheet. As long as I'm doing something like

`SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE FIELD1 = ?`

and setting the parameter source appropriately things work fine. However if I try something like

`SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE FIELD1 IN (?)`

Any attempt to provide a value like `1,3,5,7` the query seems to only pay attention to the first value in the list, not the whole source (so using `1,3,5` I get rows with a 1 in the corresponding field, and with `3,5,7` I get rows with a 3 in the corresponding field).

Is there a way for me to provide a list of values to use as the parameter value in an IN operator in the SQL query that I'm totally missing?

**EDIT**

I'm putting the list of parameter values in a single Excel field. Excel also automagically prepends the field value with `'`, as it does to escape values that it needs to treat as text. No combination of cell formatting seems to get rid of the `'` character.

Providing `(1,3,5)` in the query body instead of `(?)` works as expected; it's only when trying to use an excel cell as a dynamic parameter that things don't work.

Comment: Does `SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE FIELD1 IN (1,3,57)` works as expected? Do you have `1,3,5,7` in the same one cell, or each number in its own cell?